# How to print name of color on seaborn palplot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Suppose I have a Seaborn palplot like:

```
import seaborn as sns
flatui = ["#9b59b6", "#3498db"]
sns.palplot(flatui, size=3)
```

Is there anyway to print the color values on each square?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by first grabbing the axis object and then using `ax.text`

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

flatui = ["#9b59b6", "#3498db"]
sns.palplot(flatui, size=3)
ax = plt.gca()

for i, name in enumerate(flatui):
    ax.text(i, 0, name)
```

[image]